# popups/modals/dialog window data scraping

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, beautifulsoup

Is it possible to scrape data from popups, modals or dialog windows?

for example

https://tenders.procurement.gov.ge/public/?lang=en

I need email addresses from the users>suppliers and you can see users list, but I must open popup window in order to check any info about user.

So how could I scrape all emails from these popups ? is it possible?

first screen: 
 [image]

second screen: 
 [image]

third screen: 
 [image]

Comment: You'll often get more helpful answers if you can provide more details on your request. For example, if you could show how you've attempted to solve this problem by sharing a code snippet, you'll often get more helpful answers. Questions in the form of "Is it possible" are often too open ended to get you an answer.

Comment: Thanks for info! I am new user, so I will take into account in future! Also i didn't try any code yet, because i have no idea how to scrap. I just add beautifulsoup and request to pycharm and tried andrej-s answer, everything worked fine !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `requests.session` for the task:

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

base_url = 'https://tenders.procurement.gov.ge/public/?lang=en'
url = 'https://tenders.procurement.gov.ge/public/library/controller.php?action=org_list'
profile_url = 'https://tenders.procurement.gov.ge/public/library/controller.php?action=profile&org_id='
num = re.compile(r'(\d+)')

with requests.session() as s:
    
    # load cookies:
    s.get(base_url)
    
    soup = BeautifulSoup(s.get(url).content, 'html.parser')
    
    for tr in soup.select('tr[onclick]'):
        n = num.search(tr['onclick']).group(1)
        soup2 = BeautifulSoup(s.get(profile_url + n).content, 'html.parser')
        email = soup2.select_one('td:contains("E-Mail") + td')
        print(email.text)
```

Prints:

```
xxx@yandex.ru
xxx@gmail.com
xxx@gmail.com

...and so on.
```

Comment: you are the best bro ! Could you also add in code how can i extract these emails from all pages (3287 pages) ? Or how can I set a range of pages ?